# How to Change Date Column value to today by selecting choice column in sharepoint list validations

Tags: list, validation, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a Date column in my sharepoint list and one choice column(with values 1 to 6), so when I select the value 6 then the value to Date column must be the today's date and when I select another value then the value of Date column must be blank.

I have tried this

```
=IF([choiceColumn]="6",[DateColumn]=TODAY(),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please below formula in the list validation.

=IF(AND([choicecolumn]="6",[datecolumn]=TODAY()),TRUE,IF(AND([choicecolumn]<>"6",ISBLANK([datecolumn])),TRUE,FALSE))

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the **List validation** settings for your requirements.

Try using either of below formulas in your list validation settings:

```
=IF([choiceColumn]="6", IF([DateColumn]=TODAY(),TRUE,FALSE),ISBLANK([DateColumn]))
```

OR

```
=IF([choiceColumn]="6", IF([DateColumn]=TODAY(),TRUE,FALSE),IF(ISBLANK([DateColumn]),TRUE,FALSE))
```

You can find the detailed steps to add list validation formula in my answer at: [List validation if then syntax](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298168/list-validation-if-then-syntax/298171#298171)

---

**Notes**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.